# master child table entries from single source table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have below 3 tables "#tblData", "#tblMaster" and "#tblChild", where I need to split "#tblData" into 2 other tables "#tblMaster" and "#tblChild".

In "#tblChild" table, I need Identity Key from "#tblMaster" along with other data from "#tblData" table.

```
Create Table #tblData (Id int, UniqueKey VARCHAR(10), DateTimeNow DATETIME, UpdateBy VARCHAR(10))
insert into #tblData values (1, 'uq1', getdate(), 'abc'), (2, 'uq2', getdate()+1, 'xyz')
--select * from #tblData
create Table #tblMaster (MasterId INT IDENTITY(100,1), DateTimeNow DATETIME, UpdateBy VARCHAR(10))
create Table #tblChild (ChildId INT IDENTITY(10,1), MasterId INT, UniqueKey VARCHAR(10), DateTimeNow DATETIME)
```

I am trying with MERG, but not able to insert identity value from "#tblMaster" to #tblChild".

Below cursor solves my issue, but looking for better replacement,

```
Create Table #tblData (Id int, UniqueKey VARCHAR(10), DateTimeNow DATETIME, UpdateBy VARCHAR(10))
insert into #tblData values (1, 'uq1', getdate(), 'abc'), (2, 'uq2', getdate()+1, 'xyz')
--select * from #tblData
   create Table #tblMaster (MasterId INT IDENTITY(100,1), DateTimeNow DATETIME, UpdateBy VARCHAR(10))
create Table #tblChild (ChildId INT IDENTITY(10,1), MasterId INT, UniqueKey VARCHAR(10), DateTimeNow DATETIME)

declare @id int
DECLARE @MyCursor CURSOR
SET @MyCursor = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT Id FROM  #tblData 
OPEN @MyCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor INTO @id
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
declare @UniqueKey VARCHAR(10) declare @DateTimeNow datetime
declare @iIdentity int
create table #OutputTbl (Id Int, UniqueKey VARCHAR(10),  DateTimeNow DATETIME)

select @UniqueKey = UniqueKey, @DateTimeNow = DateTimeNow from #tblData where Id = @id

INSERT INTO #tblMaster(DateTimeNow, UpdateBy) SELECT DateTimeNow, UpdateBy FROM #tblData where Id = @id
SELECT @iIdentity=SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO #OutputTbl values (@iIdentity, @UniqueKey, @DateTimeNow)
select * from #OutputTbl
drop table #OutputTbl

FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor INTO @id
END
CLOSE @MyCursor
DEALLOCATE @MyCursor

drop table #tblChild
drop table #tblMaster
drop table #tblData
```

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. Lots of product specific SQL there...

Comment: The query in the question looks like SQL Server. If I'm wrong please edit the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this simple case there is no need for cursor.

You can use [`MERGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) together with [`OUTPUT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause. `OUTPUT` clause in `MERGE` allows to access columns from both source and destination tables.

**Sample data**

```
Create Table #tblData (Id int, UniqueKey VARCHAR(10), DateTimeNow DATETIME, UpdateBy VARCHAR(10));
insert into #tblData values (1, 'uq1', getdate(), 'abc'), (2, 'uq2', getdate()+1, 'xyz');

create Table #tblMaster (MasterId INT IDENTITY(100,1), DateTimeNow DATETIME, UpdateBy VARCHAR(10));
create Table #tblChild (ChildId INT IDENTITY(10,1), MasterId INT, UniqueKey VARCHAR(10), DateTimeNow DATETIME);
```

**Query**

`MERGE` can insert, update and delete, but we need only simple insert, so the join criteria is always false (`1=0`).

```
MERGE INTO #tblMaster AS Dest
USING
(
    SELECT UniqueKey, DateTimeNow, UpdateBy
    FROM #tblData
) AS Src
ON (1 = 0)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT
    (DateTimeNow
    ,UpdateBy)
VALUES
    (Src.DateTimeNow
    ,Src.UpdateBy)
OUTPUT inserted.MasterId, Src.UniqueKey, Src.DateTimeNow
INTO #tblChild(MasterId, UniqueKey, DateTimeNow)
;
```

**Check and clean up**

```
select * from #tblData;
select * from #tblMaster;
select * from #tblChild;

DROP TABLE #tblData;
DROP TABLE #tblMaster;
DROP TABLE #tblChild;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a column to your #`tblMaster` to save old `Id` from `#tblData`

```
Create Table #tblData (Id int, UniqueKey VARCHAR(10), DateTimeNow DATETIME, UpdateBy VARCHAR(10))
create Table #tblMaster (MasterId INT IDENTITY(100,1), OldId int, DateTimeNow DATETIME, UpdateBy VARCHAR(10))
create Table #tblChild (ChildId INT IDENTITY(10,1), MasterId INT, UniqueKey VARCHAR(10), DateTimeNow DATETIME)    

insert into #tblData
select * 
from (
    values 
    (1, 'uq1', getdate(), 'abc'), 
    (2, 'uq2', getdate()+1, 'xyz')
) d (Id , UniqueKey , DateTimeNow, UpdateBy  )

insert into #tblMaster
select Id, DateTimeNow, UpdateBy
from #tblData

insert into #tblChild
select MasterId, UniqueKey, d.DateTimeNow
from #tblData d
inner join #tblMaster m on m.OldId = d.Id

select * from #tblChild
select * from #tblMaster

drop table #tblChild
drop table #tblMaster
drop table #tblData
```